# Included file thinks its in the root, while its in a sub folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis-7, include, include-path

I'm using the latest version of CodeIgniter. In my application I have to include a PHP file, like 'example.php'. I really need this file, because rewriting it to CI would take to much time. The include is just used, to include some old stuff in a frame.

The point: The include works fine, but the included file thinks its in the root while its really in a sub folder.

The file should be in:  foo/bar/example.php. 
Nevertheless the file actually works, but in that file I also have to include other files.

Things tried:

1. Including the includes in the example.php via the base url (rather than ../../secondInclude.php)
2. At that point it can find the second include, but it gives a big browser error (lost connection to the server);
3. Tried PHP chdir, but gave the same result as point 2.

I'm not sure if its a CI problem, or my server (IIS7) or something else.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the outputs of __ DIR __ and similar PHP magic constants?

Comment: Firstly dont use terms like "file thinks". Secondly show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Like I said, the output of the current directory is the root folder, while it should be 2 sub folders down. The code that ive tried is very simple: A include to example.php from a CI controller (this works). The example.php then says its in the root (while its not) and the includes in the example.php to other files simply do not work. If I use paths like ../../foo.php (in example.php) it says it cannot find it. If I use a path from the root, like: <?=base_url()?>.'folder1/folder2/bar.php then I get 'connection lost' from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

When including a FIle Look at the root `index.php` file

```
// Path to the system folder
define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

// Path to the front controller (this file)
define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

// Name of the "system folder"
define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));

 // The path to the "application" folder
 define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
```

so if the file you want to include is inside  `application/` directory

use `APPPATH.'path/to/file'.EXT;`

Another Example

suppose you created a new file in a new directory inside application directory;
`application/custom_folder/custom_file.php`

to include this file you need to determine where your file is located,

then use the `PATH` defined above.

so to include you must use

`APPPATH.'custom_folder/custom_file'.EXT` , the `.EXT` is just `PHP`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your included files are kept in **includes** folder in views

then you can easy to include that files with:

```
$this->load->view('includes/example.php');
```

works like

```
include 'includes/example.php'; // in Core PHP
```

Comment: The include itself works. The problem is that, this included file says it is in the root, while its in a sub folder. This gives problems with other includes in that file, since those aint working.